# wxWidgets 3.0 - new features and functions, additions and replacing deprecated ones

Tags: c++, user-interface, wxwidgets

I have a question for developers who use wxWidgets.

I have just started learning wxWidgets 3.0, without any prior experience with GUI programming . After just a little searching and asking, I have found out that the latest version includes many new very useful features and functions, some of them replacing deprecated ones. The one most often mentioned new function is Bind(), that replaces Connect() and event tables.

I am following [this tutorial](http://zetcode.com/gui/wxwidgets/) and [this tutorial](http://hosannahighertech.co.tz/forums/showthread.php?tid=60), as well as a few simple samples from [library documentation](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/page_samples.html). Since these tutorials and the samples are mostly from previous versions, they mostly don't include the newest changes / additions in wxWidgets 3.0 .

I would like to know... what are the most prominent new functions and features, that have been introduced with wxWidgets 3.0, that a newcomer to wxWidgets should definitely learn about ? Thank you.

Comment: Did you read [this](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0.0/overview_changes_since28.html) and [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxwindows/files/3.0.0/changes.txt/download)?

Comment: @KristianDuske - Hi, yes I have read them, thank you for the comment anyway. I believe you can imagine that no matter how complete the change log is, it doesn't prove very instructive to a newcomer, comparing against someone who has used many previous versions of the library for a while =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have already found out about `Bind()` which is important as you should replace any appearance of `Connect()` in the old examples or tutorials with it -- and also seriously consider replacing the static event tables with it as well.

Another thing important from this point of view are Unicode changes: many pre-3.0 posts and examples use `wxT()` (or `_T()`, which is exactly the same thing), but it's not needed at all with wxWidgets 3.0. You should also ignore any discussions of Unicode vs ANSI builds as there is only one build of wxWidgets 3.0, compatible with both Unicode and ANSI builds of the previous versions.

Something that is not new in 3.0 but still doesn't seem to be widely known is [wxSizerFlags](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_sizer_flags.html) using which makes the code using sizers much more readable. You still need to understand how the sizers work however (this hasn't changed) and you may still choose to use XRC instead of writing this code in C++ at all (this isn't new neither).

Other than that there are a lot of additions in 3.0 (e.g. web view, ribbon and property grid libraries), but no other really important breaking changes.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer, it is just what I was looking  for. I would kindly like to ask you to expand your answer further, in case you think of any other new addition that deserve mentioning. Or recommended replacements for methods used in most tutorials/examples.